# CSS class question for multiple elements

Tags: css

```
table.rightlist td
{
    text-align:right;
}

table.rightlist th
{
    text-align:right;
}
```

The above code works, but when I tried making

```
table.rightlist td,th
{
    text-align:right;
}
```

the th,td isn't working, it only aligns for td, but not for th

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fully specify each selector when comma separating them,

```
table.rightlist td,
table.rightlist th
{
    text-align:right;
}
```